# Getting tax refund from Germany to a non-EU bank account after leaving?

Tags: germany, taxes, relocation, foreign-employment

I lived and worked in Germany in 2020 and have recently submitted my Steuererklärung for that year. I'm back in my home country (Canada), and have closed my German bank account. Thus, in section of the tax form where I had to provide my bank details, I left this blank, because we do not have the SEPA bank account system in Canada and so there was no way for me to enter my details (i.e. we do not have an IBAN number).

Is there any way for me to enter my bank information via ELSTER, or should I try to get in contact directly with the Finanzamt? Or will they get into contact with me once they've calculated my tax refund?

I can't seem to find any information on this specific scenario, your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here is an eight year old answer to this question: [Überweist das Finanzamt auch die Steuerrückzahlung an ein ausländisches Konto? (Finanzen, Steuern, Überweisung)](https://www.finanzfrage.net/g/frage/ueberweist-das-finanzamt-auch-die-steuerrueckzahlung-an-ein-auslaendisches-konto). I assume the Finanzamt knows you are now in Canada?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, in the Hauptvordruck ESt 1 A I provided my Canadian address, and I also deregistered from my German address before leaving. I suppose all I can do is email the Finanzamt and hope they will get back to me...